# How to make only current year appear once?

Tags: php, date, drop-down-menu

I am have this query below that is a drop down for year (from 1900-current).  I am using a $variable to show a previously chosen year first in the drop down for an edit form. It works except that for all other years 2011 is also repeated with them.  How do i tweak it so that $y shows first and then all years underneath that?

Code:

```
    <select name="year">
<?PHP for($i=date("1900"); $i<=date("2011"); $i++)
        if($year == $i)
            echo "<option value='$y' selected>$y</option>
     <option value='$i' selected>$i</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='$y' selected>$y</option>
     <option value='$i'>$i</option>";
?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Is `$y` supposed to be `$year`?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `date("1900")` instead of just `1900`?

Comment: +1 @Michael, I don't get this for-loop. Seems to me like it's looping a lot of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
    <select name="year">
        <?php for($i=1900; $i<=date('Y'); $i++) {
        if($i == date('Y'))
            echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        }
?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Or even better:

```
<select name="year">
    <?php for($i=1900; $i<=date('Y'); $i++)
        echo "<option value='$i' ".(($i == date('Y')?'selected="selected"':'')).">$i</option>";
    ?>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

And backwards

```
<select name="year">
    <?php for($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
        echo "<option value='$i' ".(($i == date('Y')?'selected="selected"':'')).">$i</option>";
    ?>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <select name="year">
<?PHP 
      echo "<option value='$year' selected>$year</option>
      for($i=1900; $i<=2011; $i++)
        if($year != $i)
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
     <option value='$i'>$i</option>";
?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: thanks! and how to i reverse it? instead of 1900-2011 how do i do 2011-1900? i tried swtiching but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to change the `for` line by `for($i=2011; $i<=1900; $i--)` This will count "backwards".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `$y` is, but I guess `$year` is the current year:

```
   <select name="year">
    <?php 
    for($i=date("1900"); $i<=date("2011"); $i++)
    {
            if($year == $i)
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$i.'</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```